# Error : statusCode 400 with bad request in Node js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

i have worked with node js with joi and hapi i have create a registration with post method.

when i call this by this url "http://localhost:9000/api/users" and parameter header content `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It show Error like:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"name is required"}
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message, The Joi schema that you've defined requires a name field to be present.